# Connection Issue with Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, server, samba

I have a strange issue with my Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.
Following is what I have:

- SAMBA Server
- Ubuntu GUI Installed
- Static IP Address

I took the Server off-line for about say 1-2 months for Maintenance in the House. Afterwords When I re-connect it. Server does not connect to Internet nor to the LAN.
I checked the Eth1 from command menu and from GUI and its in tact. there is no changes. but somehow it does not work.... any idea what should i do?

Comment: Can you try `sudo service network-manager restart` and then try to connect again?

Answer (score 0):

I did not completey understand your question but it could be caused by this:
As of v197, udev no longer assigns network interface names according to the wlanX and ethX naming scheme. If you are coming from a different distribution or are reinstalling Linux and not aware of the new interface naming style, please do not assume that your wireless interface is named wlan0, or that your wired interface is named eth0.

You can use the command ip link to discover the names of your interfaces.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  My connection is wired. The server was working perfectly until I took the server offline for few months.  In fact once I comment out static IP Address and assign dhcp, it works perfectly so.... basically I am bummed.... in limbo.... Help!

Comment: Oh BTW, I have not assumed anything there are two network interface cards. 1 been 10/100 & the other been gigabit.  I am using the Gigabit Ethernet card & which is Eth1. & have assigned an ip address which was working perfectly but now it does not.... i just want to know how to fix it, i know it can't be the card cuase when i assign dhcp it works.... So...?

Comment: If you have not upgraded the system everything should work. My proposed solution was just for the case that you have switched to a newer version of your system. In this case it would be possible that the name of the ethernet interface is not named eth0 or eth1 but something else like v23w. In this case it would be necessary to keep that name for the allocation of the static ip.

Comment: I have checked in network manager on Ubuntu Desktop, Both the NICs shows the exact name (eth0 & eth1) as in the Server..... well, I need the Ubuntu desktop functionality that's Y i updated it... but it does not fall into place as it worked for few months untill i took the whole server off line for house maintenance.... now I am dead in the water... earlier once i give the static IP Address in the console to eth1, both the Server and Ubuntu Desktop Network is working as it should... but not anymore...!